# Mail is not in proper format in yahoo

Tags: php, email

when user register or clicks on forgot password mail is send. it looks fine in gmail and other accounts but it is shown in html format in yahoo.

**code is**

```
   $embody="<p>Dear ".$data['name']." </p>
                <p> Thank you for registering with JCA Associates.  Please log into your account to complete your candidate profile and upload your CV </p><br/>
                <p> JCA Associates</p>
                <p> <img src='".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/themes/images/logo.png' width='100' height='60'></p>";
                //} else {
                //  $embody="<p>Dear ".$data['name']." </p><p> Thank you for registration with us!</p><p> Best regards,<br/> JCA Team</p>";
                //}
                $message  = '<html dir="ltr" lang="en">' . "\n";
                $message .= '  <head>' . "\n";
                $message .= '    <title>Welcome to JCA Associates</title>' . "\n";
                $message .= '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">' . "\n";
                $message .= '  </head>' . "\n";
                $message .= '  <body><p> ' . html_entity_decode($embody, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</body>' . "\n";
                $message .= '</html>' . "\n";
```

it is shown like this in yahoo.
http://screencast.com/t/wDWixSBI

Comment: the full mail sending code is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't added the HTML headers to the function that triggers the email call.  If you're using `mail`, add these headers:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Where `$subject`, `$to`, and `$headers` have the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adding following to your email code and it will work like a charm.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/"."MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html\n";
mail("$sendto","$subject","$embody","$headers","$from");
```